# How does Grails handle Database triggers?

Tags: grails

I have an existing oracle database with triggers when a record is created. The documentation indicate to register evenlisteners for update and create. Do anybody know best practice.

Comment: If you have more than one application using the same database then use database triggers. This will help your data integrity

Answer (score 0):

What happens after or before the record is created when you use triggers is totally dependent of the db that you're using. As @aldrin says, it will help consistency if there's another application handling the same database.

I suggest you to use the events if there're plans to support more than one database vendor because you avoid the work to translate triggers between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if Oracle triggers can be replicated in grails - the answer is that the event binding can be replicated (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping).  as far as, what you are doing in PL/SQL for the trigger logic, that might not translate as easily.